# Error(389/703 with Wildfly 11 server

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

When i'm want to start a wildfly server, I write in terminal /opt/wildfly11/bin$ sudo ./standalone.sh
But after that I get several mistakes, such below:

> =========================================================================
>
> JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly11
>
> JAVA: java
>
> JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M
>   -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
>
> =========================================================================
>
> 12:45:34,953 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version
>   1.6.1.Final WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.GetAccessibleDeclaredFieldAction
>   (jar:file:/opt/wildfly11/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/security/elytron-private/main/wildfly-elytron-1.1.6.Final.jar!/)
>   to field java.security.AccessControlContext.context WARNING: Please
>   consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.GetAccessibleDeclaredFieldAction WARNING:
>   Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal
>   reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations
>   will be denied in a future release
>
> 389 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7)
>   MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   org.wildfly.management.http.extensible:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   org.wildfly.management.http.extensible: java.net.BindException: Адресу
>   вже використано /127.0.0.1:9990   at
>   org.jboss.as.server//org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>
> 12:45:44,***703 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed -
>   address: ([
>       ("core-service" => "management"),
>       ("management-interface" => "http-interface") ]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException:
>   Адресу вже використано /127.0.0.1:9990"}} 12:45:44,**715 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("core-service" => "management"),
>       ("management-interface" => "http-interface") ]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException:
>   Адресу вже використано /127.0.0.1:9990"}}*****  WildFly Full
>   11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) stopped in 32ms

Comment: Please dont start WildFly with sudo - it does not need root permissions. If you want to install it as service, use scripts in `docs/contrib/scripts`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that your port is used by an other application. (google translate :) ) you can check it with a command:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :9990
```

You can set a **port offset** to wildfly by setting system property:

```
bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
```

But be aware you need to specify port when connection to CLI after:

```
bin/jboss-cli.sh --controller=localhost:10090 -c
```

Also any other service will be using port increased by 100 in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be that port 9990 is already bind. However, regarding first warning. Are you using security manager? Which version of java do you use? Do you use wildfly 11 final?